# While executing this program the char function does the returning the variable.i dont know why?

Tags: c

Here in the program, findnumber function getting  array elements and the value to be searched via STDIN.The output which i expected is if the value equals any one of the element in the array it displays YES or else NO.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char findNumber(int,int[],int);``
int main()
{
    int n,a[10],s;
    char c;
    c=findNumber(n,a,s);
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
char findNumber(int arr_count, int arr[], int k) 
{
   int i=0,j,flag;
   char y="YES";
   char N="NO";
   scanf("%d",&arr_count);
   scanf("%d",&k);
   for (j=0;j<arr_count;j++)
   {
      scanf("%d",&arr[j]);
   }
   while(i<arr_count)
   {
      if(arr[i]==k)
         flag=1;
      i++;
   }
   if(flag==1)
      return y;
   else
      return N;
}
```

warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from
pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 char y="YES";
warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from
pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 char N="NO";

Comment: Instead of `char y="YES";`, try `const char *y="YES";` Or just drop those and change `return y;` to `return "YES";`. And change `char findNumber` to `const char *findNumber`. Though personally I would just have it return a `bool`/`int` instead.

Comment: Turn on all your compiler warnings, and fix the problems they reveal.  There should be a lot of them.

Comment: why does a function named `findNumber` contains reading array input from console? Hint: it's a rhetorical question meant to make you think. Hint2: it really really shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string constant like `"YES"` or `"NO"` is an array of characters, not a single character, so you can't store them in a `char`.

You need to declare `y` and `n` as `char *` so they can point to the string constant and change the return type of the function accordingly.

```
const char *findNumber(int arr_count, int arr[], int k) 
{
    const char *y="YES";
    const char *N="NO";
    ...
```